# Solidity Integer constant expected

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I try to get a loop run through all structs associated with the caller address, but I can't get my head around this warning. I think I understand the problem, but can't get my head around what should I do differently to achieve this result the other way.

The error I am getting:

```
TypeError: Integer constant expected.
  --> minitest.sol:30:31:
   |
30 |             balance += Wallet[walletNumbers[msg.sender][i]].balance;
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My code simplified just for the error part:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^ 0.8 .0;

contract MiniTest {

    uint nextWalletNumber = 0;

    struct Wallet {
        address owner;
        uint balance;
        uint debt;
    }

    Wallet[] public walletInfo;

    mapping(address => uint[]) public walletNumbers;

    function createWallet() public {
        Wallet memory newWallet = Wallet(msg.sender, 1000, 0);
        walletInfo.push(newWallet);
        walletNumbers[msg.sender].push(nextWalletNumber);
        nextWalletNumber++;
    }

    function allWalletsBalance() public view returns(uint) {

        uint balance;

        for (uint i; i < walletNumbers[msg.sender].length; i++) {
            balance += Wallet[walletNumbers[msg.sender][i]].balance;
        }

        return balance;

    }

}
```

Is there another way to achieve this for loop and take out uint from all structs associated with that address?

Comment: @Yilmaz please do not add the [web3] tag to questions. Add the specific library tag instead for a question about a web3-based library. "Web3" itself is a meta tag that does not add any value and means too many different things to be useful

Comment: @TylerH I thought `web3` means decentralized web. so anything related to smartcontract or blockchain should be related to web3. Or what I am missing?

Comment: web3 is a buzzword term and a meta tag; it's not meaningful (you can't be an expert in web3 for example...), further, web3 _itself_ is not a programming term, concept, entity, etc. There is lots of stuff (like smart contracts, solidity language, web3js or web3react libraries, etc) that _are_ programming related _and_ specific; those are better tags to use. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging for more info on kinds of useful tags).

Comment: For example for almost 3 years people used the web3 tag to refer exclusively to the web3js library (and sometimes web3py or similar early library); only later did people start to use it as a catch all for what they _really_ meant which is usually something like "solidity" and "smartcontract". I have been endeavoring to retag all these questions bit by bit (so as not to flood the front page) with the actual tags they need (e.g. web3 -> web3js or web3 -> web3dart or web3 -> web3py). And where they are just talking about some vague web3 tech, I just remove the tag.

Comment: @TylerH just for curiosity, how long does it take to remove a tag? you said you had removed the tag but still being used?

Comment: @Yilmaz I said I _am_ removing it. The tag still has over a thousand uses dating back to ~2017, so it will take a long time to remove it in a non-disruptive way. Mid-2023 I'm guessing.

Answer (score 2):

although I could not figure out the relationship between your state variables, this line of code is

```
 balance += Wallet[walletNumbers[msg.sender][i]].balance;
```

`Wallet` is a struct. instead you should be using `walletInfo` the name of the array.

```
        balance += walletInfo[walletNumbers[msg.sender][i]].balance;
```